# Laravel Error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am getting the following error while trying to insert into the table `users_basics`

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setAttribute(), 1 passed in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\msadi\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php
>   on line 592 and exactly 2 expected

Here is my controller code:

```
public function create()
{
   $userId = '10';

   $userBasics = new UserBasics;
   $userBasics->user_id = $userId;
   $userBasics->save();

   return redirect('users');
}
```

Here is my model:

```
class UserBasics extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'users_basics';
    protected $primaryKey = null;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];

    const UPDATED_AT = null;
    const CREATED_AT = null;
}
```

Here is my user_basics migration:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_basics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->bigInteger('adhaar_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('college_roll_no')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->nullable();

            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

I have tried adding `UPDATED_AT`, `CREATED_AT` and `PrimaryKey` to the table but none worked. The `user_id` is being inserted into the `users_basics` table but the error continues to show.

Comment: as i can see your table name is `sadi_users_basics` inside migration. `users_basics` is different table ?

Comment: @Kul It's the same table, I have updated the question.

Comment: I'd suggest you step through the code with a debugger to find out where the faulty code comes from. Alternatively, extract a [mcve] to post that here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should modify your model:

```
class UserBasics extends Model 
{
    protected $table = 'users_basics';
    protected $primaryKey = null;
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['user_id'];
}
```

Comment: Previously, I added *protected $primaryKey = null;* to the Model. Afterwards, I face this issue, and after removing this line I see my code working. Can you please explain your code?

Answer (score 0):

because you not have field for Timestamp.
please add like this.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sadi_users_basics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->bigInteger('adhaar_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_no')->nullable();
            $table->string('college_roll_no')->nullable();
            $table->date('dob')->nullable();
            $table->timestamp(); <---- just insert this.
            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

also, if you want to use softdelete then add `$table->softDeletes();`

it will make Deleted_at field in the table.

enjoy coding~!